# Is it possible to add middle click option to close tabs?

Tags: 11.10, tabs

I would like to know if it is possible to close tabs in several applications like gedit or empathy by doing click on the middle mouse button (wheel or scroll button) like the same behaviour of Chrome and Firefox.

I would like to do it without having to use Compiz since i am not running Compiz (Using **Ubuntu Classic (No effects)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middle-click is used for Paste in Ubuntu. All you have to do to **Copy** is select any text and then Middle-click to **Paste**.

There must be a way to change that behavior. Perhaps you could even do it without going into the source code and re-compiling.

<strike>Do you really want give up the middle click paste?!</strike> Middle-click paste is one of the greatest conveniences of X desktops. It saves me a lot of time and I believe it kept me from getting the Carpal tunnel syndrome.

While tiring to figure how to get the closing-tabs-by-middle-clinking behavior, closing tabs one can close tabs by pressing **Ctrl-w**.

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't realize that the question author was talking about middle-clicking **ON the tabs** to close them. Both functionalities can co-exist.

Comment: What's the matter with having both of these facilities?  I can't think of a common, useful situation in which one would need to middle click on a tab to paste something.  Middle click does different things in different situations already anyway.<br>
Also, I didn't actually know about middle click to paste, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Echogene. Good question (+1). I'm always looking for ways to save time and delay my Carpal tunnel.

Comment: Uhm excuse me, but this answer doesn't answer anything ... or is there something wrong with me?

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer the question here: this can only be achieved per application.

For **gedit** there is [*tabs-enhanced*](http://code.google.com/p/tabs-enhanced/).